# Where does the error event go in Angular when using a factory?

Tags: angularjs, error-handling

I have the code below working but now I need to create a handler for when an error occurs but not sure how I insert that.. Do I put it in the factory on in the main method?

```
MsaApp.factory('Msa', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/api/Place/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
```

});

```
 $scope.delete = function () {
    debugger;
    var id = this.msa.PlaceId;
    Msa.delete({ id: id }, function () {
        $('#todo_' + id).fadeOut();
    });
}
```

edit 1:

```
 $scope.delete = function () {
    debugger;

    // var id = this.msa.PlaceId;

    var config = {
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'api/Place/:id',
        data: { 'some': 'data' }
    }

    $http(config)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
    });


    //Msa.delete({ id: id }, function () {
    //    $('#todo_' + id).fadeOut();
    //});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would sugest moving all DOM manipulation to a directive and let the controller do what its supposed to do.

And to answer your question ( hope I understood you correctly ):

```
MsaApp.factory('Msa',['$http', function(http) {
    return {

        delete: function(someData) {

            var config = {
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/api/Place/:id',
                data : someData
            };

            http(config)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                console.log(data);

            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
            });



        }}

    };
}])

MsaApp.controller('ControllerName', ['$scope', 'Msa', function(scope, Msa) {

    $scope.delete = function({ id: id }) { 
        debugger; 
        Msa.delete({ id: id }); 
        $('#todo_' + id).fadeOut(); 
    };

}])
```

If your factory cant access the controller scope and you wish to return, for example messages back to the controller you need to use a promise which is explained here:
http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/

Comment: Im afraid im over my head.. http is undefined it is telling me... In the example you posted is it stand alone.. or is it using my little factory method? It seems to be stand alone.. I am really new to this. just trying to get the basics up and running and in this case that is adding to my working example the ability to capture errors from the rest calls

Comment: I pasted them in.. I tried to fix the syntax errors.. I did for the first part.. The second part something was off..  Also, I want to get the existing factory that uses $resource.. Do I need to use $http to get an event handler for errors?